# How to dispatch action from a child window?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have implemented a custom SSO service, it works fine but I would like to open a popup to request the user authorization instead of redirect him to this page.

The problem is, when the user has accepted or refused to connect his account, I need to refresh my parent window (the web app) and close the popup (authorization).

So I was thinking about dispatching an action from my popup to my parent window to refresh its state, something like:

```
componentWillMount() {
  window.opener.loginSuccess(this.props.user);
}
```

But I don't see any action from the window object.
How could we implement this feature?

Comment: Do you use modal etc. which has close state or did you implement your own popup ?

Comment: @TugrulAsik it is not a modal, it is a redirection, so it uses a window.open()

Comment: Using modal (customized) helps you to develop common components easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to the opener window a reference to the `loginSuccess` method that will dispatch the needed wanted action:

```
const store = redux.createStore(reducer);
window.loginSuccess = function(user) {
    store.dispatch(sampleActionCreator(user));
};
```

Now you can access `window.opener.loginSuccess()` from the child.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I manage popup/modal etc. into the parent component which triggers, passes params etc. to popup. 
Popup page is only responsible for presentation. All behaviours (service calls from service layer, redux binds) is into my parent component.

I pass behaviours(funcs) and props to popup, so that when I need to change sth. I just update redux state. 
It's easy to manage components when using data oriented achitectures like redux.

My suggestion to you, If you don't have to, don't use dummy presentation components like behavioral components which has own methods, own behaviours.

Comment: I do the same, but here we talk about another use case since the popup will redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) between parent and child windows.
look at the example inside the link, and notice there that you will need to implement event listener to the message you want to receive. so action can be dispatched accordingly.

Comment: Interesting API, but it looks like the child window can answer his parent only after receiving a message (to access "event.source"), and in my case, the parent cannot know when the child will achieve his redirect.

So the parent has to be ready to handle a message coming from the child without sending him a message first (since the user can wait 2s or 2min before accepting or refusing the connection...)

Comment: hey, sorry but i think you still can do this with the postMessage. I have good example in my blog but with jQuery, you can easily translate it to any framework you want. http://www.dimagimburg.com/authentication-and-login-popup-window-handling-for-social-medias-code-example/ , shortly what you need to do is to make a callback page that handles the message posting to the parent page. if you have any questions about it feel free to ask me